# Open Source Syslog Daemon for Windows

Tags: windows, open-source, logging, syslog

Can anyone recommend an open source Syslog Daemon for Windows (specifically Windows 2008 64bit).

Thanks

Comment: Why was this question closed?  This question relates to "software tools commonly used by programmers" as quoted from the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Kiwi Syslog](http://www.kiwisyslog.com/kiwi-syslog-server-overview/), or [Star Syslog daemon lite](http://www.thestarsoftware.com/syslogdaemonlite.html) - free, but not OSS.

or [Syslog for Windows](http://syslog-win32.sourceforge.net/) - free, and OSS.

or [BazSysLog](http://www.oocities.org/bazsyslog1/) - free, gui-based log capture, but not necessarily a 'daemon' as requested.

Comment: I've used Kiwi for a low volume app. Worked fine.

Comment: BazSysLog seems to have disappeared along with Geocities...

Comment: The link above for BazSysLog is broken, but you can find it [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Misc-Networking-Tools/BazSyslog.shtml) or [here](http://www.oocities.org/bazsyslog1/).

Comment: syslog-win32 is great, worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://github.com/thenotandy/FantailSyslogServer) is one written in C# that logs to SQL Server. Only the source is available for download, but it has a ton of potential.

Comment: link is dead. Do you remember the name of the project?

Comment: I uploaded it to GitHub because I couldn't find a working link.