# How to organize semaphors for writing several java processes to one text file

Tags: java, file-io, concurrency, semaphore

We have several Java processes that write to one text file from time to time. These are not threads of the same virtual machine, but separate `java.exe` processes that are running from command line. These processes write to the same log file. We used `canWrite`...

```
while (!Log.canWrite()) {
    System.out.println("File: " + LogPath + " is locked, waiting...");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

... but it seems don't work. We get the following error:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method).
```

**`The Question:`**

what are the best practices for organizing **semaphors** in sutiations like this? It would be great if the solution wasn't too resource consuming, thus hugely affecting the total performance.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using different log files for different processes. Or are you using this file to communicate between the processes?

Comment: No, I'm using this file as an activity log for all processes. If I used different files it would be hard to merge them into one whole...

Comment: You can use http://vigilog.sourceforge.net/ to merge multiple log files into one for viewing. This is a tool I created and no longer actively supported, but it should work normally. Maybe there are better tools out there currently.

Answer (score 3):

You can synchronize access to the file using [`FileChannel.lock()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock%28%29). You can obtain a `FileChannel` from [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#getChannel%28%29).

**EDIT** But in your case it will be solving a wring problem. What you need is a centralized logging server. Refer to this question for more details: [Centralised Java Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100760/centralised-java-logging)

Comment: Centralised Java Logging looks too serious to use it here. Briefly why we need semaphors: we run four java-based Fitnesse autotests simultaneously and track results in one text file. We could write to 4 different files but it would be hard to merge them. Here, Centralised Java Logging with SoccerAppender looks too complex solution...

Comment: @Racoon: messing with file locks is almost guaranteed to cause you lots of headache. Are these processes continually running or do they all finish and produce 4 log files? If they finish and you need to analyse logs, then I'd go with merging files, it's much easier.

Comment: currently, they are writing in the same file. By merging I mean merging chronologically. It would be hard to merge records from 4 different files in chronological order. It's very strange Java doesn't have built-in functionality for writing to the same file without lots of headache. I thought it was a typical thing needed to many developers...

Comment: @Racoon: don't you have timestamps in those log files?

Comment: I can write timestamps in those files myself. Would you suggest writing to seperate files and then merging? It's strange nobody seriously recommends using Java built-in facilities.